# Authenticating users Ionic App with Rails Devise as a backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, ionic-framework

Has anyone successfully implemented authentication on an Ionic application that uses a Rails application with Devise as a backend? If so, what implementation did you use to that end? Please Provide me a Good Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

we've just written a tutorial covering exactly this( [Rails and Ionic - Authentication with Devise](http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/8/26/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-two) ). It also comes with github example repos you can download and try out.

Comment: This is a very helpful guide. But if you want to use devise helpers for authentication (i.e. before_filter :authenticate_user!) you will have trouble.

Comment: I would rephrase that to if you want to use before_filter and authenticate_user! then you have to be careful and make sure that you return a json response to the frontend so you can handle any errors but yeah thanks for the heads up.

Comment: and.. What about of User registration with devise and ionic?

Comment: Link-based answers are not great... the link is dead.